# Rhodes mobile: How to get the current action?

Tags: mobile, rhodes

I'm creating a pagination partial here, and I would like it to work from any controller/action.

I'm trying something like: url_for(:query => {:page => 2}) for example.
it works, but it redirects for the controller_root?page=2
I need it be controller_root/current_action?page=2

I tryed url_for(:action => action_name, :query => ...) but it didn't work.
is there any method that returns the current action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found it at `@request['action']`